# Audit trasspasing information

Tags: windows-server-2019, files, audit, file-server

I would like to know if there is a way to audit what files a user is "passing" from the file server to their local environment.

I have the event viewer enabled but I can only see which file the user has accessed or deleted, but we need to know if any employee is transferring files to their local environment and which files they are.

As much as I have searched I cannot find a way and as a last resort I come to you to see if you can give me a hand.

Thank you.

Comment: There are Data Loss Prevention applications for this. These tend to be for managed endpoints that you control. Here's an example of the solution that Microsoft has: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/endpoint-dlp-learn-about